# Spring Mass Damp - Differential Eq

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The molecular bond due to intermolecular forces is flexible. A diatomic molecule like 
oxygen ($O_2$), if disturbed, will oscillate to and fro the equilibrium position 
( $R_0$ or $x = 0$ minimum potential energy) approximated by the equation:
$$
    U\ddot{x} + k*x = 0
$$
V(R) - Potential Energy
$$
    V(R) = 1/2k (R - R_0)^2 = \frac{1}{2}kx^2
$$
the U for ($O_2$) is $1.33 \times 10^{-26}$ and $k=1195$

1. What is the Natural Frequency of $O_2$
2. What will happen to the molecule if it is forced by an external
   source to vibrate with a freq equal to its natural freq?

---

Hello Community, I am a Software major thats taking a class in DE... something about the wording of this question is giving me problems. I typically dont find Spring/mass questions very hard, but i just cannot figure out what im missing here:

I calculated that :
$$
    w = 2.999749\times 10^{14}
$$
and
$$
    x(t) = A \cos(w t) + B \sin (w t)
$$
but i cannot figure out what the initial conditions would be so i can solve for A and B.

Comment: "i cannot figure out what the initial conditions would be so i can solve for A and B." You are not requested to solve for A and B.

Comment: but the equation is incomplete.